# Pandaboard ES OMAP4460 USB Ports Technical Specifications Question

Tags: usb

[Technical specifications for Pandaboard ES OMAP4460](http://www.mouser.com/new/pandaboardorg/pandaboardES/?cm_sp=homepage-_-newproducts-_-OMAP4460+Pandaboard+ES) shows that it has 3 USB ports.

- 1x USB 2.0 High-Speed On-the-go port
- 2x USB 2.0 High-Speed host ports

My question is that what's the difference between an On-the-go port and a host port?
Does a host port allow the Pandaboard to act as a slave when connected to a PC via USB?
Does a OTG port allow the Pandaboard to act as a slave when connected to a PC via USB?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts StackExchange - read the [FAQ] to see what kind of questions can be asked. There's three questions in one post, one question at a time. As this is related to hardware and Pandaboard, it may be outside of the scope of this site. Please check the Google's newsgroups on this as Pandaboard is very frequently mentioned especially in *Android Building*.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about 'Pandaboard'.  But a USB OTG port, acts as both Master & Slave.  Depending on the spare pin of the mini usb cable (if its grounded or not). A Host port aka your PC can only talk to salves like Flash/Hard drives.  usb otg can talk to Flash drives & also act like a Flash Drive too.